# Is there a way to request sign-up redirect in Cognito Hosted UI via Amplify JS SDK with React?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm extending the [example](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social/q/platform/js#full-samples) from the official Amplify docs but the problem is that I'd like a third button for **direct** redirection to the Hosted UI's Sign Up page:

```
<div>
  <p>User: {user ? JSON.stringify(user.attributes) : 'None'}</p>
  {user ? (
    <button onClick={() => Auth.signOut()}>Sign Out</button>
  ) : (
    <button onClick={() => Auth.federatedSignIn()}>Sign In</button>
    <button onClick={() => Auth.federatedSignIn(??)}>Sign Up</button>
  )}
</div>
```

Sadly, I can't find a way to utilize federatedSignIn() to that effect and Amplify API docs don't seem to help either. Any ideas? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I fell back to using Cognito Hosted UI urls directly. Originally I had avoided this because sometimes during signin, after redirect back to my App the authorization code wasn't exchanged to get a token automatically by Amplify. Now it seems to be working.

If anybody has other ideas feel free to share